# Show that ${\bf x} \cdot A^t {\bf y} = {\bf y} \cdot A{\bf x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathcal M_n (R)$ and ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in R^n$.

How can I show that:

$${\bf x} \cdot A^t {\bf y} = {\bf y} \cdot A{\bf x} \, ?$$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** note that for real vectors $u,v:u\cdot v= u^T v$

**Second hint:** we can write
$$
x \cdot A^T y = x^T (A^T y) = (x^T A^T) y = (Ax)^T y
$$

Comment: Can you expand on this please?

Comment: I expanded a bit. See if that's any clearer.

Comment: Ah yes it does, thanks for the help